# Dynamically add options for widget

Tags: ajax, 8, entities

I'm developing a field widget for Drupal 8, similar to 'select' but with more functionality. Since the number of options is large and should be determined after querying an external API I was planning to retrieve options from ajax calls.

However [AJAX - How to dynamically add options to select?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24894/ajax-how-to-dynamically-add-options-to-select) states that it's not possible. What will be the possible workarounds or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used is below for anybody else who might have similar questions.

You can use the **autocomplete_route_name** property to get the options for autocompletion.

```
$element += array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $items[$delta]->value ?: NULL,
    '#autocomplete_route_name' => 'example.myroute',    //your route name
    '#placeholder' => $this->getSetting('placeholder'),
);
```

The route should be defined in your *module_name*.routing.yml file

```
example.myroute:
    path: <url>
    defaults:
      _controller: <controller>::<method>
    requirements:
      _permission: <permission>
```

Hope this helps :)